# Opensuse virtual machine not working

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, 32-bit

my opensuse virtual machine freeze's my host when it starts
Host: Ubuntu 16.04 ( 32 bit )
Software: Virtualbox
VM: OpenSUSE Tumbleweed ( 32 bit )
Help me!
or can i use a other version of the vm?

Comment: Your issue isn't entirely clear to me, however are you suffering from lack of resources (eg. RAM) and thus it's not hanging/freezing, just thrashing due to the lack of resources, and thus very very slow (not frozen at all, you're just not giving it enough time to cope with limited resources, it'll take hours instead of moments due to extra work required to overcome lack of ram etc). More details may help.

Comment: Add details about your host/guest settings, are you using Virtualbox?

Comment: i am using it and i am using a old windows xp pc to ubuntu pc

Comment: it does it on other vms and guis

Comment: even sometimes it like frezzes my host somehow my vm takes a loooonnnnnnnnng time to load.

Comment: there is glitch and windows 10 virueses

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu anymore but sometimes i do!